# Unable to delete files from drive in Banshee

Tags: banshee, music, uninstall, delete

When I imported all of my music from my iPod into Banshee, I got all of the wrong music, so I decided to delete it all. Now it says that there is no such file or directory, so it won't delete the music. Now I have low disk space. 
Thanks in advance for anyone who can help...

Comment: How did you delete your music? And off of what? Please provide some more info on what you did to delete your music and off of what device...

Comment: Can you provide some more details such as perhaps a screenshot of exactly what you're trying to do and what error it causes?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

That does seem strange behavior, especially as banshee handles ipods pretty well.

As a temporary fix you can use gtkpod (in the software centre). This is probably the most comprehensive ipod handler for linux. From here you should be able to delete files and/or repair the library.

If this doesn't work, there are (quite complicated) ways of restoring your ipod on linux, but I suggest you just find a friend with itunes and do it on there.